# Delta table partition folder name is getting changed

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, delta-lake, data-processing

I am facing an issue where the expected date parition folder should be named in format date=yyyymmdd, but instead writing as -
[image]

Sometimes for each parquet file created in delta path, it's creating a seperate folder.

I don't see any issues with the source data or pyspark code, since it's working perfectly for other data sources. Also , the same data is writing perfectly in seperate delta path.

It's not causing any issues since in delta table date format is captured correctly and can be queried. But if I change the folder names manually in the storage account, then it throws error.

I am expecting data should be written for each date in a specific folder which should be named with the date value -

[image]

Since, the pyspark code is creating a date column from timestamp value like this - **2021-10-27T11:56:41.380416Z** .I tried to convert the field into timestamp and then extract the date, but it then creates the folder as **date=**. The existing code was working for this database earlier , but suddenly started behaving this way

Comment: I don't fully understand. You want to get folder name as 'date=yyyymmdd' and are getting just 'date='?

Comment: No, I am getting folder names in random alphabets (in first image), where the expected names of folders should be in the format given in 2nd image.

Comment: Provide your code and error details you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the response. But it was an issue with delta table version. To remove or rename any delta table column we need to change in read version 2 and write version 5. But that causes the issue I was facing. And this change is irreversible as per databricks.

For a delta table with default read version 1 and write version 2, the same code works fine and date folders

Answer (score 0):

You try below code using `partitionBy` function.

Below is the timestamp i am having.

[image]

Converted to date and replacing  `-` to empty.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
w_df = df.withColumn("date",regexp_replace(to_date("timestamp","yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'"),"-",""))
```

[image]

Next, while write to delta, you need to give partitionby with this date column.

[image]

You said you manually changed the folder names, that gives you error since the delta logs will be remembered these partitions and doesn't match when it is changed manually.